# Is there a way to speed up updates on a Neo4j Graph?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in Neo4j (3.5) containing approximately 12m nodes and 16m edges. The graph is running on a RHEL VM with 8 vCPU Cores and 8gb of Memory.

When performing updates on the graph such as the one below, I'm seeing that the updates take approximately 15 seconds to complete.

I've reviewed the Neo4j indexing recommendations and cannot find anything that indicates it will speed up the update at all. The schema for the graph shows I have create an index on the matching attribute; `:Liability(Liability ID) ONLINE`

```
MATCH (n {`Liability ID`: {liability_id}}) 
SET n.`Creditor Reference`= {reference},
n.`Liability Type`= {liability_type}, 
n.`Liability Sub-Type`= {liability_subtype}
RETURN n.`Liability ID`
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I've also tried replacing the index with a constraint with the following schema: `:Liability(Liability ID) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)`, this did not speed up the update and instead made it 1 second slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an index is associated with a *label* AND a *property name*, in order to use an index you must specify the *label* and the *property name* in your `MATCH` pattern. If you do not specify the label in the pattern, then Cypher is forced to scan through all nodes, which prevents it from using your index.

For example, this should cause the Cypher planner to generate a plan that uses your index (the only real change is in the `MATCH` clause):

```
MATCH (n:Liability {`Liability ID`: {liability_id}}) 
SET
  n.`Creditor Reference` = {reference},
  n.`Liability Type` = {liability_type}, 
  n.`Liability Sub-Type` = {liability_subtype}
RETURN n.`Liability ID`;
```

Comment: Ah! very good, the updates went from 10-15 seconds to 10-20ms by specifying the label.